# Import Java class from another Module

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, module

I'm trying to modularize my Android Studio project. I got two different features that require a lot of resources and classes. I found out that using different modules is a way to achieve that.
I added a new module named `einstempeln` in the main `app` module like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkQIE.png)

Now I want to start a activity that is inside the `stempeln` module from the `app` module. I can't manage to do that whatever I try.

I already added the include in the settings.gradle like that: [settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtbIH.png)

I found online to implement the module in the build.gradle.kts like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MX3j.png) but it doesn't show up as autocomplete.

I didn't find anything that could fix this online. Isn't modularization very common in Android Studio projects or what other way is there to structure a project?

Comment: What you found online should be correct: `implementation(project(":<project-name>"))`. That's how you have one project depend on another project within the same Gradle build.